# CSS Grid carousel - last items are shrinking

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a simple carousel with CSS Grid and I almost got it right but there's one detail that I can't fix.

Here is the main code

```html
<div id="car">
    <div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
#car{width:100%; overflow:hidden;}
    #car > div{display:grid;grid-template-columns:25%;grid-auto-flow:column;}
```

Unfortunately in this case only the first item gets the 25% with and the rest go very small (probably `min-content`).

[image]

Before I tried another thing using `auto-fill`

```css
   #car > div{grid-template-columns:repeat(auto-fill, 25%);}
```

In the above case the first 4 elements would be fine, but anything that is theoretically outside of the initial viewport, shrinks. How do I stop the shrinking and forcing each item to have the same width?

[image]

In here I moved the internal div 500px to the left so the two big images are actually the last 2 of 4 and the ones next to them are those who, for some reason, do not honour the width;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what you need is `grid-auto-columns`, not `grid-template-columns` to define the width of the columns here:

```css
#car {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#car > div {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-columns: 25%;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}
img {display:block;width:90%;margin:auto;}
```

```html
<div id="car">
    <div>
        <div class="item"> <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100"></div>
        <div class="item"> <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100"></div>
        <div class="item"> <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100"></div>
        <div class="item"> <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100"></div>
        <div class="item"> <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100"></div>
        <div class="item"> <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100"></div>
        <div class="item"> <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-columns
>
> The `grid-auto-columns` CSS property specifies the size of an implicitly-created grid column track or pattern of tracks.

While

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns
>
> The `grid-template-columns` CSS property defines the line names and track sizing functions of the [grid columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/grid_column).

Comment: oh geez.. that easy.. somehow with all the options for grids I never  really focused on `grid-auto-columns`. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
grid-template-columns:25%
```

I hope you understand
this code set only 1 column.
What your saying to do is that make the first item fix to 25%, for the other i don't care.

If you want the remaining items also 25%
you need to write

```
grid-template-columns:repeat({numberofitem}, 25%)
```